# axes.set_xticklabels breaks datetime format

Tags: python, matplotlib

im trying to force my will onto this matplotlib graph. When I set `ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)` it works fine like in the [upper graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEMbT.png).
However when I add  `ax1.set_xticklabels((date),rotation=45)` the timeformat reverts to matplotlib time like in the [lower graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEMbT.png).

Both use the same input time variable. I also tried `ax1.plot_date()` but that only changes the look of the graph not the timeformat.,

```
    date_1 = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)(time_data) # makes a datetimeobject from unix timestamp
    date = np.vectorize(mdates.date2num)(date_1) # from datetime makes matplotib time
    myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M')

    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((10,3), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4)
    ax1.xaxis_date()
    ax1.plot(date, x)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt) 
    ax1.set_xticklabels((date),rotation=45)#ignores time format
```

Any ideas how I can force the custom timeformat onto the xticklabels? I get that xticklabels directly reads and displays the date variable but shouldnt it be possible to make it stick to the format? Especially if you later want to add xticks in custom date locations.

All ideas appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A locator specifies the locations of the ticks. A formatter formats the ticklabels at those positions. Using a formatter, like

```
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M'))
```

hence works well. However, using `set_xticklabels` after speciying the formatter, removes the DateFormatter and replaces it with a `FixedFormatter`. You will hence get ticklabels at automatically chosen positions but with labels that do not correspond to those positions. The graph will hence be labelled incorrectly. 
Therefore, you should **never use `set_xticklabels` without specifying a custom locator**, e.g. via `set_xticks`, as well.

Here there is no need to use `set_xticklabels` at all. The formatter alone is enough.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

time_data = np.array([1.5376248e+09,1.5376932e+09,1.5377112e+09])
x = np.array([1,3,2])

date_1 = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)(time_data)
date = np.vectorize(mdates.date2num)(date_1)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M')

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((4,4), (0,0), rowspan=4, colspan=4)
ax1.xaxis_date()
ax1.plot(date, x)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Aha, this comes closer to I how imagined it. Is there also an axes equivalent for plt.setp for when one wants to style different subplots differently?

and to understand that right, set_xticks will adhere to the dateformatter as long as I dont interfere with set_xticklabels? That would make handling custom xtick positions also much easier

Comment: For different subplots you'd use `plt.setp(ax1.get_something())`,   `plt.setp(ax2.get_something())` etc. `set_xticks` sets the locator. You may use any formatter with that (except the `AutoDateFormatter`)

Answer (score 0):

Alright I think I got it now.

```
    str_dates = []
    for i in time_data:
        j = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(i)
        k = j.strftime('%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M')
        str_dates.append(k)
    print(str_dates)
    ax1.set_xticklabels((str_dates),rotation=45)
```

Im not sure why this doesnt work with vectorize, but taking each date one by one removes  the error source that the arrays are giving me.

@iDrwish: thanks again you pushed me in the right direction.

Comment: **Never use `set_xticklabels` without specifying a custom locator**, e.g. via `set_xticks` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can coerce your time format by converting the `datetime` object to string.

You will have to do special handling of the dates if that are in utc-format:

```
from datetime import datetime
str_dates = [datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M') for timestamp in date]
ax1.set_xticklabels((str_dates),rotation=45)
```

Comment: I get the idea, makes total sense. but your first line seemingly cant be applied to an array. 
I tried `str_dates = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.strftime('%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M'))(date_1)` but that doesnt recognize date_1 as a datetime object for some reason.
Lastly im unfamiliar with the syntax of your first line. What are the square brackets doing? and what is supposed to be achieved with the `for timestamp in date`?

Comment: My syntax is for a list comprehension. Are you using an np.array?

Comment: Ah, I didnt know one could do lists like that *wow *much learn

and yes time_data is one column from an numpy array

Comment: `np.array` support iteration, so there shouldn't be a problem. What is the error message you got?

Comment: `--> 311     str_dates = [timestamp.strftime('%d-%m-%Y/%H:%M') for timestamp in date]

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: time_data should be pure unix timestamps but if the array is a float type than this could indeed cause a problem. although its weird that the date2num is working without issues.

When I use utcfromtimestamp now i get module `'datetime' has no attribute 'utcfromtimestamp'` no idea where this comes from. 
I also tried to convert the array to list `str_dates = date.tolist()` which raised similar errors. 
I have to try a selfcontained example. Thanks for your detailed answers though!

Comment: Make sure you use the import statement as well.

Comment: damn the 2nd "datetime" in dt.dateitme always gets me :D

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if it met your inquiry.

Comment: although.. almost 

when I use `dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)` the dates start in 1970. what is the (timestamp) doing? shouldnt that be date_1?

Comment: Not following, can you share the data of date_1?

Comment: Yes ill make a selfcontained example

Comment: Sorry for downvoting this. The reason is that you should never just use `set_xticklabels` without specifying any locations. Since people tend to use such structures if they find them on stackoverflow, seeing a `-1` on the answer is hopefully the only way to prevent them using this, and hence prevent them from asking new questions about this not working.